# Is there any way to turn off eviction in kubelet?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubelet, evict

According to [this article](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSBS6K_2.1.0/installing/pod_eviction.html) it is the only way to preserve system pods when eviction might happen. I was wondering if there is chance to turn off eviction mechanism and keep all pods - allow starvation in kubelet configuration? I would like to keep pods from certain namespaces always up even if node is low in resources.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions regarding configuring Kubernetes should be posted on [sf]

Answer (score 2):

You can use priority classes to prioritise your important pods over others. You can also use `system-cluster-critical` or `system-node-critical` as the `priorityClassName` to mark the pod as critical if you have PodPriority feature gates enabled. See [Guaranteed Scheduling For Critical Add-On Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/guaranteed-scheduling-critical-addon-pods/) for details

Comment: May i use these PriorityClasses in custom namespaces?

Comment: Yes. The priority Class Name is specified on the pod hence it works irrespective of the name space it belongs to https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption/